# Save images to sandbox?

Tags: xcode, image, sandbox

I have a for loop that runs the code below to download a large amount of images (kind of like a book of images) from the server.

```
-(id)imageRequest:(NSString *)imageurl :(const float *)width :(const float *)height
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, *width, *height)];
    [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.jpg"]];
    return imageView;
}
```

But I would like to save these images in sandbox so the app can access them even if there is no internet.  But how do I save them and open them when the internet is down in a way that allows the app to still load them in the right order as a book of images?

I've been looking at this
http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/image-caching-in-iphone-sdk/

Sorry I am rather new at xcode, but thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

setImageWithURL: placeholderImage: is not a UIImageView function, i see it in an uiimageview categorie called SDWebImage ( [github](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/) ) so you can use it to cache images and open them when internet is down. you can try to use hjcache to ( [github](https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache) ) or AFnetworkin ( [github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) ). but i advice you to use SDWebImage because it simple and powerful.